# TreeTable scroll to item

Tags: scroll, vaadin, treetable

I work with TreeTable. When button is clicked I want to expand items and select one of the items inside of the parent items. But also I want to scroll to the selected item.
If item is visible (all parent items are expanded) everything works perfect. But if it is not visible at first (some parent items are collapsed) scroll comes to the nearest visible parent.

My code looks something like this:

```java
testButton.addListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
       // expanding items for selected one
       ItemId parentId = selectedItem.getParent();
       while (parentId ! = null) {
         treeTable.setCollapsed(parentId , false);
         parentId = parentId.getParent();
       }
       // select the item
       treeTable.select(selectedItem);
       // scroll to seledcted item
       treeTable.setCurrentPageFirstItemId(selectedItem);
    }
});
```

Is there any solution to scroll to the selected item, not to the nearest visible parent item of the selected item ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I put this into the first line of the method:

```
treeTable.focus();
```

It looks like it works. (Vaadin 6.7.9)